# Teamviewer login alert and notifications?

Tags: remote-access, notifications, teamviewer, alert

Is there a way to be notified (either by email, phone, etc) whenever a remote device connects to my PC via TeamViewer?

Answer (score 0):

Go into menu
*Extras > options > Computers and contacts*
and **check** "Notify me when partners sign in",
then click OK:

[image]